# Responsive menu doesn't close even after browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Responsive Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header id="topbar">
    <p>Some title</p>

    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="nav-trigger">
        <span><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></span>
    </div>

    <nav class="mobile-menu-enabler">
        <span></span>
    </nav>
</header>

<nav class="mobile-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<!-- Begin main sample site content -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amet...</p>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Ludica Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: azure;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Begin Menu Code */
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.menu ul:last-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 3px;
}

.menu ul li>:hover {
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
}
/* End Menu Code */

/* Mobile Menu Begin */
.mobile-menu-enabler {
    display: none;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.mobile-menu {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mobile-menu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
}

.mobile-menu ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.mobile-menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: darkkhaki;
}
/* Mobile Menu End */

/* Mobile Trigger Button */
.nav-trigger {
    display: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-trigger:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
}
/* End Mobile Trigger Button */


/* Dummy wrapper stuff */
#wrapper {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
/* End Dummy wrapper stuff */

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-menu-enabler {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-trigger {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }

    /*.mobile-menu {*/
        /*display: block;*/
    /*}*/
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Begin document ready function
    var headerHeight = $("#topbar").height();

    $(".nav-trigger").click(function() {
        $(".mobile-menu").slideToggle(400)
    });

    $(".mobile-menu").css("top", headerHeight);

    $("#wrapper").css("top", headerHeight);
}); // End document ready function
```

When the page loads I have a top header bar which contains dummy links. When the browser width is shrunk below the breakpoint at 900px the responsive menu kicks in, at this point upon clicking on the "3 bars icon" the dropdown menu appears as expected.

However, if I were to resize the screen back to full size without first closing the drop down menu, it continues to stay even after the browser is fully expanded.

How can I make the drop-down menu to automatically "untoggle" at the point of growing wider than the breakpoint of 900px?

Thanks

EDIT: Screenshots:
[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

[image: Third image]

[image: Fourth image]

Here's how I'd like it to behave: 
[callmenick.com/lab-demos/10-simple-responsive-navigation](http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/10-simple-responsive-navigation/) 
When the mobile navigation is fully expanded, it automatically slides up once the browser window is expanded

Comment: Seems like an extreme edge case, but you would have to do something with onresize.

Comment: Please provide fiddle link or live example thanks

Comment: @epascarello 
Nope that's wrong as there would be a massive performance issue. I've seen this done before in other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Javascript to toggle the display when you click that menu bar icon, it pretty much nullifies the 'display' css for .mobile-menu to some extent (since it is changing the style after the css has already loaded). So you'll need to toggle the UL display value (child), and not the .mobile-menu (parent).  That way the responsive .mobile-menu css stays in tact... I believe this is what that example site you mentioned does.

```
<nav class="mobile-menu">
    <ul class="mobile-menu-items">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

keep css for .mobile-menu as display: none on large screens, and display:block for smaller.  Then for new class ".mobile-menu-items" you can initially set that to display: none, and toggle that with your jQuery:

```
$('.nav-trigger').click(function(){
    $('.mobile-menu-items').slideToggle();
});
```

Alternatively you could toggle the visibility instead of the display.

```
$('.nav-trigger').click(function(){
  if ( $('.mobile-menu').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
    $('.mobile-menu').css('visibility','visible');
  else
    $('.mobile-menu').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

updated.extremely crude example. resize

```css
ul{list-style-type:none;}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  
  #big li{display:inline-block;width:100px;height:32px;border:1px solid red;}
  #small{display:none;}
  
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  
  #big{display:none;}
  #small{display:block;}
  .smaller{display:none;}
  #small li:hover~ul{display:block}
  .smaller:hover{display:block;}
  
  }
```

```html
<ul id="big">
  <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
  </ul>
<ul id="small">
  <li>home1</li>
        <ul class="smaller">
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>

   <li>home2</li><ul class="smaller">
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
  </ul>
```

Comment: That's an easy solution, but the menu will appear expanded as soon as the screen shrinks again. This does not collapse the menu, it just hides it

Comment: I'd like to avoid using resize please, and none of those media query tricks.

Here's how I'd like it to behave:
http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/10-simple-responsive-navigation/

When the mobile navigation is fully expanded, it automatically slides up once the browser window is expanded.

Comment: @Elgringorrible      the jquery slideup sets the display property to none, I quote `Once the height reaches 0 (or, if set, to whatever the CSS min-height property is), the display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.` , I'm just doing it faster .

Comment: @jack , thats a media query probably. if you're not using js resize or media queries you  have no way that I know of to get the browser screen resize...

Comment: @Billy : granted, but with your method, if you shrink the page again, the mobile menu will appear extended, right away, because you don't _retract_ it, you just hide it.@JackSparrow : first, you're already using media queries in your own CSS. Second, why wouldn't you want to use them or resize() ? There aren't many other ways... I agree with Billy

Comment: Here's that pages tutorial:
http://callmenick.com/2013/12/21/simple-responsive-navigation-menu/

More specifically the code the guy is using is:
http://pastebin.com/2D28t3kz

Comment: The reason resize should not be used is because the jQuery code will fire on every resize if that function were to be used - which is a performance hog.

Comment: @ Elgringorrible updated answer with extremly crude code but it doesn't show it extended straight away, if it's been set to display none, whether thats by jquery or css then it would need to be set to display block or inline or whatever to be shown  extended again

Comment: @JackSparrow123 the example you gave does not collapse the menu either, it just hides it... you'll notice however you "left" the menu on a smaller screen it will stay in that state when you make the window larger and then smaller again.  I believe they keep the container / parent element display:block on small screens and display:none on large screens, while toggling the child element with the menu button.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually retract the mobile menu (and not just hide it in CSS) when the window gets too wide, try this :

```js
var $window = $(window), // caching the objects for performance
    $mobileMenu = $(".mobile-menu");

$window.resize(function(){

  if( $window.width() > 900) $mobileMenu.slideUp();

})
```

Comment: the jquery slideUp uses display:none when it gets to 100% complete, which is just hide it in css, check their docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

Comment: Have you ever used SlideUp()? This will _collapse_ the menu before hiding it. So the menu won't show again when you shrink the window, unlike your method. The downvote is unfair.

Comment: i didn't downvote. and if you read my comment it says, as does the jquery website "  display:none when it gets to 100% complete". It doesn't set it straight away, that would collapse it.

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding each other and actually saying the same thing. I didnt say _you_ downvoted me, I have no way to know who did. It was just unfair, but "someone" canceled it :)

Comment: No one cancelled it, I just upvoted this answer because it is a good one.  Though it may keep repeating the slideUp animation as the window is resizing above 900px.  Could always check first if $(''.mobile-menu').css('display') == 'block' before calling that code